# Show content on hover (without affecting card height)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, gsap

I have a block which contains content that appears on hover. The way the effect should work is:

- `.hoverCard` shows base content by default (content in .hoverCard__showOnHover is hidden)
  User hovers over .hoverCard at which point `.hoverCard__showOnHover` reveals its contents and the `.hoverCard__body` translates up (giving it that "open" effect)
- A visual of the above can be seen in my demo, but I cannot get the animation to work neatly.

The issue(s) I'm running into are:

- using `visibility: hidden`, `opacity: 0` and `height: 0` still reserves space for `.hoverCard__showOnHover`. Meaning that if by default, `.hoverCard__body` has 40px padding at the bottom, and `.hoverCard__showOnHover` is 100px in height, 140px space can be seen on .hoverCard without the user hovering
- The only way I know can prevent the reservation of space is by using display: none. However, when I hover over the card, I need to give it a display property to showcase the content, which gives the card a jumping effect (as the height is being introduced on hover). In addition to this, my card also grows in height (I want the effect of content being revealed and opening upwards, rather than growing .hoverCard as it does in the demo)
- To try resolve the above, I've tried giving `.hoverCard__showOnHover` height gradually by using `GSAP`.  But no luck, as it still presents the above issues

Is there a way I can tackle this? It doesn't have to be using GSAP, I've just tried GSAP in an attempt to resolve the above issues.

```js
const hoverCard = document.querySelector('.hoverCard');
const hoverCardBodyShowOnHover = document.querySelector('.hoverCard__showOnHover');

hoverCard.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  gsap.to(hoverCardBodyShowOnHover, { duration: 0.5, display: 'block', height: 'auto', ease: 'power4.out' });
});

hoverCard.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  gsap.to(hoverCardBodyShowOnHover, { duration: 0.5, height: 0, ease: 'power4.out', onComplete: function() {
    this.targets()[0].style.display = 'none';
  }});
});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --yellow: #FFE775;
}

/* general */
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--black);
}

section {
  margin: 100px 0 300px 0;
}

/* card */
.hoverCard {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
}
.hoverCard * {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__body {
  transform: translateY(-75px);
}
.hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__body .hoverCard__showOnHover {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  transform: translateY(75px);
}
.hoverCard__header {
  height: 350px;
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}
.hoverCard__showOnHover {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hoverCard__body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 30px 40px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <!-- img here -->
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

       <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
             <!-- img here -->
           </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader 2</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>


      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is a visual of the default version of the card (see right card) and how the hover interaction works (left card):

[image]

Notice how the card height doesn't increase. Instead, the body moves up (within the card) to reveal the content.

### Edit:

Based on Kooilnc's answer:

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --yellow: #FFE775;
}

/* general */
body {
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--black);
}

section {
  margin: 100px 0 300px 0;
}

/* card */
.hoverCard {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  position: relative; /* added */ 
}
.hoverCard * {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__body {
  transform: translateY(-75px);
}
.hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__body .hoverCard__showOnHover {
  /* opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  height: */ auto;
  overflow: initial; /* added */ 
  height: auto; /* added */ 
  max-height: 100px; /* added */ 
  transform: translateY(75px);
}
.hoverCard__header {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}
.hoverCard__showOnHover {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0; /* added */ 
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out; /* added */ 
  overflow: hidden;  /* added */ 
}
.hoverCard__body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 30px 40px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <!-- img here -->
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

       <div class="col-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
             <!-- img here -->
           </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader 2</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>


      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Also, what do we need to define a number for `max-height: 100px;`? What if the content size is unknown and needs to be dynamic?

### Edit 2

Latest approach:

```css
:root{
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --black: #000000;
  --yellow: #FFE775;
}

section{
  padding: 150px 0;
}

.hoverCard {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 180px; // seems I need this to maintain height
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  border: 1px solid var(--black);
  
  /* only on non touch devices
  ================================== */

  @media (hover: hover) {
    * {
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    &:hover {
      .hoverCard__body {
        transform: translateY(-75px);
      }
      .hoverCard__showOnHover {
        display: block;
        max-height: none;
        overflow: visible;
      }
    }
  }

  &__showOnHover {
    display: none;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  /* only on touch devices
  ================================== */

  @media (pointer: coarse) {
    &__showOnHover {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  }

  /* =============================== */

  &__header {
    height: 350px;
    background-color: var(--yellow);
  }

  &__body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    color: var(--white);
    background-color: var(--black);

    &-text {
      margin-bottom: 60px;
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <!-- img here -->
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

       <div class="col-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
             <!-- img here -->
           </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader 2</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>


      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

With the above:

- It causes unnecessary spacing above `.hoverCard__body` (should only be padding top `30px`).
- The entry animation is jumpy (content just appears and the translate isn't smooth)
- The exit animation jumps down in height quick also (because of the display none property taking effect)

Comment: Hi @ugroi - The animation using GSAP is still quite glitchy / jumpy, as it was in my original demo. I have however, tried to use your demo and achieve it without the use of GSAP, but still have the same effects. See my updated question above

Comment: `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible`

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to set the text to show to `max-height: 0` *and* `overflow: hidden`. Here is a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.item.first {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d0/Queen_Clementia_of_Hungary.jpg") no-repeat top left;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 150px;
}

.collapsible {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.collapsible .header {
  background-color: #EEE;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.item .collapsible .collapsibleTxt {
  max-height: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: initial;
  color: #444;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: normal;
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.header:hover  .collapsibleTxt {
  overflow: initial;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item first">
  <div class="collapsible">
    <div class="header">Who's that?
      <div class="collapsibleTxt">
        It's Clementia of Hungary!<br>
        <a target="_blank" 
           href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clementia_of_Hungary"
        >Find out more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Kooilnc, this approach still causes the card to expand on hover, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I've added a visual to my question to showcase what I'm after

Comment: Hi @Freddy, I've changed the example code, does the snippet now show what you mean?

Comment: The effect does look like what I'm after! However, I've tried applying it to my own markup and CSS, and cannot emulate it. I've updated my original question to showcase the latest attempt and also left a question on how I can make it more dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using GSAP along with your markup from "Edit 2". For accessibility, I made a small change to your markup (added tabindex to the cards) so that the content can be revealed on focus for keyboard users. I don't know why the preview doesn't work here but I also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/wolaka/full/xxyPYMm).

```js
let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".hoverCard");

cards.forEach(card => {
  let cardContent = card.querySelector(".hoverCard__body");
  let hiddenContentHeight = card.querySelector(".hoverCard__showOnHover").clientHeight;

  gsap.set(cardContent, {
    y: hiddenContentHeight + 20
  });
  let tl = gsap.timeline({
      paused: true,
    })
    .to(cardContent, {
      y: 0,
      duration: .7,
      ease: "power3.out"
    });
  cardContent.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
    tl.play();
  });
  cardContent.addEventListener("mouseleave", (event) => {
    tl.reverse();
  });
  card.addEventListener("focusin", (event) => {
    tl.play();
  });
  card.addEventListener("focusout", (event) => {
    tl.reverse();
  });

})
```

```css
.hoverCard {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hoverCard:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.hoverCard__body {
  background: black;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .8;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.hoverCard__body-text {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.hoverCard__header {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}

.hoverCard__header img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.3/gsap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative" tabindex="0">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
                commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative" tabindex="0">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <img src="https://loremflickr.com/500/900" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader 2 with longer text</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover <a href="#">Link</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show only the `button`, and you know its height, you can do it only with css.

If the content has a dynamic height, you can use a minimum of javascript in combination with css variables.

I've provided a basic example below, combining the two options to give you a starting point:

```js
setCardHeightProperty()
window.onresize = setCardHeightProperty;

function setCardHeightProperty() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card-with-dynamic-content').forEach(card => {
    card.classList.remove('active');
    card.style.removeProperty('--card-height');
    card.style.setProperty( '--card-height', card.querySelector('.card-content-hidden').offsetHeight + 'px' );
    setTimeout( () => card.classList.add('active'), 100 );
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 420px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.card {
  --card-height: 24px;
  --offset-top: 16px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card:hover .card-body {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.card-img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  flex: none;
}

.card-body {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: transform .4s;
  transform: translateY( calc( var(--card-height) + var(--offset-top) ) );
  margin-top: calc( (var(--card-height) + var(--offset-top) ) * -1 );
  flex: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  will-change: transform;
}

.card-content {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.card-content-hidden {
  margin-top: var(--offset-top);
}

.cart-desc:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: var(--offset-top);
}

.card-btn {
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card-with-dynamic-content:not(.active) .card-body {
  transition: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3 class="cart-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="cart-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content-hidden">
        <button class="card-btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3 class="cart-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="cart-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content-hidden">
        <button class="card-btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-with-dynamic-content">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3 class="cart-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="cart-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content-hidden">
        <div class="cart-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
        <button class="card-btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card card-with-dynamic-content">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="" class="card-img">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-content">
        <h3 class="cart-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="cart-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content-hidden">
        <div class="cart-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <button class="card-btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Transition the `max-height` from `0` to `*your card height*`.

This uses your own HTML code and classes, so adding the CSS here should integrate into your project without issue.

**Important things to note:**

- Run the snippet to see an example which uses your intended image and layout.
- Added `box-sizing: border-box` to the card, which makes padding easier to work with.
- Pay attention to the comments regarding **padding**, which explain where these need to be consistent.

*In the 1st example*, notice the delay on the hover-out? That's because the `max-height` is reducing from `360px` to `0px`, but the **showOnHover** section is only around `250px` height at the start. The time spent reducing the `max-height` from `360px` to `250px` is cause of the delay.

*In the 2nd example*, we use a **button** instead. There are **full instructions in the comments** to explain where we change our CSS to allow for this. There is a benefit to using a single constant-height element, such as a **button**, in the **showOnHover** section. As we know the height of the element, we can avoid the delay seen in the 1st example by setting the max-height to match the `button + margin-bottom`. This is fully explained in the CSS code.

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --yellow: #FFE775;
}

/* general */
body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--white);
  color: var(--black);
}

/* card wrapper */
.hoverCard {
  position: relative;

  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;

  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}
.hoverCard,
.hoverCard * {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* this is important, it's a good habit to start using it! */
}

/* card header/image */
.hoverCard__header {
  height: 360px; /* the height of the card */
  background-color: var(--yellow);
}
.hoverCard__header > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.row > *:last-child .hoverCard__header {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJIDQ.png") no-repeat 85% 25%; /* background position trickery to use your image */
  background-size: 280%;
}

/* card content: wrapper */
.hoverCard__body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 30px 0 30px; /* make sure the bottom padding is 0, then note the left and right padding for later */

  background-color: var(--black);
}

/* card content: header (always visible) */
.hoverCard__body-text {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
/* card content: header (BONUS EXTRAS for 2nd example) */
.hoverCard__body-text h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
}
.hoverCard__body-text p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 0;
}

/* card content: hidden (only visible on hover) */
.hoverCard__showOnHover {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hoverCard__showOnHover *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0; /* important to ensure the hidden elements sit immediately out of view */
}
.hoverCard__showOnHover *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 30px; /* make this the same as the left and right padding of your .hoverCard__body */
}
.hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__showOnHover {
  max-height: 360px; /* the height of the card */
}
/* card content: hidden (BONUS EXTRAS for 2nd example) */
.hoverCard__showOnHover button {
  padding: 8px 14px;
  line-height: 1em;

  background-color: var(--white);
  border-radius: 500px;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hoverCard .hoverCard__showOnHover.hoverCard__onlyButton {
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* make this transition faster than the other one,
    as we're only transitioning the button's height,
    not the height of the full card */
}
.hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__showOnHover.hoverCard__onlyButton {
  max-height: calc(8px * 2 + 1em + 30px);
  /* the above calc: 
    8px * 2 = button's top and bottom padding (8px each)
    1em = button's line-height
    30px = button's margin-bottom, defined in the ".hoverCard__showOnHover *:last-child" selector
  */
}

/* layout */
.row {
  display: flex; /* easy way to arrange the buttons horizontally */
  gap: 16px;
}

.col-12.col-md-6 {
  width: 400px; /* the width of the card */
  height: 360px; /* the height of the card */
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <!-- img here -->
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
  
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <!-- img here -->
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">
              <h2>Accounting leaders</h2>
              <p>Cut costs and reduce errors.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover hoverCard__onlyButton">
              <button>Find out more</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to transition in height, and you tried it in CSS but doesn't work.

My answer is as follows:
when transitioning the height, use `max-height` but not height.

```css
:root {
      --black: #000000;
      --white: #ffffff;
      --yellow: #FFE775;
    }
    
    /* general */
    body {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      background-color: var(--white);
      color: var(--black);
    }
    
    section {
      margin: 100px 0 300px 0;
    }
    
    /* card */
    :root {
      --black: #000000;
      --white: #ffffff;
      --yellow: #FFE775;
    }
    
    /* general */
    body {
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      background-color: var(--white);
      color: var(--black);
    }
    
    section {
      margin: 100px 0 300px 0;
    }
    
    /* card */
    .hoverCard {
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 8px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: var(--black);
      color: var(--white);
      border: 1px solid var(--black);
    }
    .hoverCard * {
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }
    .hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__body {
      transform: translateY(-75px);
    }
    .hoverCard:hover .hoverCard__body .hoverCard__showOnHover {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      transform: translateY(75px);
      max-height: 400px;
      transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in;
    }
    .hoverCard__header {
      height: 350px;
      background-color: var(--yellow);
    }
    .hoverCard__showOnHover {
      max-height: 0;
      width: 80%;
      transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .hoverCard__body {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 30px 30px 40px 30px;
    }
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
            <!-- img here -->
          </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>

       <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <article class="hoverCard position-relative">
          <div class="hoverCard__header">
             <!-- img here -->
           </div>
          <div class="hoverCard__body">
            <div class="hoverCard__body-text">Subheader 2</div>
            <div class="hoverCard__showOnHover">
              <p>This will show on hover</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>


      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Harry, your demo showcases the same issues I'm trying to prevent occurring (may be because of my poor explanation). In your demo, when you hover over a card, do you see how the card grows (causing the other card to shift down)? I'm trying for that not to happen. Instead, on hover, I want the `.hoverCard__body` to grow upwards (within the cards bounds) and translate up.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Visibility:

```
.hoverCard .text-content {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hoverCard:hover .text-content {
  visibility: visible;
}
```